# How can i retrieve elements of a list between two numbers in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to output the elements of a list that are greater than 39, but less than 291, the desired output being 49.

My Code is below, i think i have just made a small mistake as the output is almost right, if someone could help me i would appreciate it as python is new to me.

```
list=[1,2,30,49,29,299,291,39,30]

for x in list: 
if x > 39 & x < 291:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `&` instead of `and`, which won't work (Python will throw an error).

```
list=[1,2,30,49,29,299,291,39,30]

for x in list: 
    if x > 39 and x < 291:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

here's an efficient way to do it without having to confuse yourself with `and` and `&`

```
lst=[1,2,30,49,29,299,291,39,30]

[print(x) for x in lst if 39 < x < 291]
```

> note: you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name since that's the name of a casting operation; e.g. `list()`

Comment: No problem, Thanks for asking!